# All values in an object are overflowing

Tags: c++

I am attempting to get a solution for a specific problem using the Breadth First Search in a Binary Tree.

If we divide the Binary Tree into layers, I am doing the calculations in the following format.

> Scan a Root Node
>
> Create its child nodes
>
> Add the reference of the child nodes to a queue > After all the ADJACENT child nodes from the same layer have been added, Scan each of them and repeat

So my code for that attempt is

```
void kickoff() {
    unsigned int size = queue.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size;i++) {
        if (queue[i]->getGoal()) {
            //Print Solution on CLI
            return;
        }
        queue[i]->verGoal();
        queue[i]->initCalc(); //Create the Next Layer of Child Nodes..
    }
    kickoff(); //Recursive Loop
}
```

This function would essentially check each layer, starting from the root layer, to the solution layer of a Binary Tree, implementing BFS properly.

The queue would be something like this

```
vector<state*> queue;
```

Once the child nodes have been calculated using the `initCalc();` function of each state in the queue their reference will be automatically added to queue.

The state object would be something like this

```
vector<state*>* queue;
//Calculate Child Nodes here
queue->push_back(&childNode);
```

With all this it should work but it doesn't. Using a lot of breakpoints and memory scans I found out the problem but no idea how to solve it.

Basically. The data in the referenced objects inside queue changes awkwardly for some reason. This change only happens when the program excecutes the kickoff function. Before that all data its exactly how it should be. The data changes to this:

[image]

The green part is the root object reference and the rest of it is just giberish. It only changes values when the `kickoff();` is called and the first line runs..

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** A few points I forgot to make:

1) Its showing the values for the root node correctly

2) The values only change to incorrect if I try and perform any function on the queue variable. If I just replace the kickoff function with normal `queue[0]->initCalc();` which is exactly the same code but without the for loop, it works perfectly. It only fails if I try anything else..

Comment: You're probably accessing out of bounds of arrays, and/or using wild pointers. Impossible to say for sure unless you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  To avoid these sorts of problems, stop using raw pointers and stop using C-style arrays.

Comment: Ill try and post a MCVE of my code soon, however I do not think that this is the case since 1) its showing the values for the root node correctly, 2) the values only change to incorrect if I try and perform any function on the queue variable. If I just replace the kickoff function with normal `queue[0]->initCalc();` which is exactly the same code but without the for loop, it works perfectly. It only fails if I try anything else..

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function `kickoff()` has no base case/terminating condition. So it should never stop. You should stop the recursive call when your work is done (i.e. the `queue` is empty, so no more children to push in it).

Also make sure that the function `getGoal()` removes the first element from the queue. If it doesn't, you'll end up pushing the same children over and over.

There may also be problems with handling pointers, but it's not ensured unless you post a complete code.

Comment: The recursive function does have a terminating code fragment, the `return` inside the if loop. It will check each node to match it with the goal state of the answer and then and only then it will terminate. To prevent duplication I have instead added a bool value to each state which toggles when a state has been computed.

Comment: Generally a recursion should be conditional with some base case avoiding it, and have different (and "shrinking") arguments